# Connect TAB to the gtkEntry

Tags: c, gtk

How do I make the tab key behave as a Enter key in a GtkEntry?
I am able to catch the 'enter' key with the signal "activated". How can I catch the 'tab' key  for GtkEntry?

```
static void enter(GtkWidget *widget, GtkWidget *entry)
{
  const gchar *entry_text;
  entry_text = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));
  printf("Entry contents: %s\n", entry_text);
}

entry = gtk_entry_new();
g_signal_connect(entry, "activated", G_CALLBACK(enter), entry);
```

In the same way, how can I get notified when the tab key is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register entry for [`"key-press-event"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-press-event) or [`"key-release-event"`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-key-release-event) and in the event callback check the key value of [`GdkEventKey`](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventKey). You can make use macros defined in  `gdkkeysyms.h` to check for "Tab" or "Enter", something on these lines:

```
...
#include <gdk/gdkkeysyms.h>
...
static gboolean
key_press_cb(GtkWidget *w, GdkEvent *ev, gpointer data)
{
    (void)w; (void)data; /* To avoid compiler warnings */
    GdkEventKey *key = (GdkEventKey*)ev;
    if(key) /* Extra check maybe redundant */
    {
        if(key->keyval == GDK_Tab)
            printf(" Tab pressed\n");
        else if (key->keyval == GDK_Return)
                printf(" Enter pressed\n");
    }
    /* Default handling of "Tab" is change of focus.
     * If TRUE is passed here, the event will not be propagated
     */
    return FALSE;
}
...
    entry = gtk_entry_new ();
    g_signal_connect(entry, "key-press-event", G_CALLBACK(key_press_cb), NULL);
...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply..:)   its able to catch tab key but i am not able to enter the text in to that entry....

Comment: Hmm that is strange, what exactly are you trying to do? You should be able to entry text. Can you post your key-press-event cb?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a bad idea as tab is used to change the focus of the application. Remember that it's important to make an application usable without a mouse, using tab in a GtkEntry for something else than changing focus will make that much harder, perhaps even impossible.